# Minimum diameter of spherically-inverted topological balls

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, differential-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, mobius-inversion

Let $U$ be the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let $S$ be a round sphere whose center is in $U$ with radius at least $\delta_1 > 0$. Suppose $B$ is a closed topological ball of Euclidean diameter at least $\frac{1}{2}$ which intersects $U$ but is disjoint from $S$ and the volume it encapsulates. Denoting $I_S$ as the spherical inversion through $S$, can we deduce that the diameter of $I_S(B)$ is bounded below by some $\delta_2 > 0$ which is independent of the specific choices of $S$ and $B$?

This claim comes up in the proof of Lemma 4.6 of Freedman-He-Wang's paper on [the Mobius knot energy](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Ebishop/classes/math638.F20/Freedman-Mobius-energy.pdf), but is left to the reader.

Comment: Yes, and a proof is a straightforward computation with points on a plane through the center of $S$. The role of $U$ is negligible: you use it to bound the diameter of $S$ from above (by 2) and the maximal distance between $S$ and $B$ from above (by $2+\delta$).